# How to remove all characters before a certain character in pandas df column in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, replace

How to remove all the characters before " \ "

```
column1

absc \ efgcvc \ Hello
hij \ klsm \ Hey
qssdrs \ uv \ yellow
```

I would like to have the output as below:

```
column1

Hello
Hey
Yellow
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `str.replace` we can try:

```py
df["column1"] = df["column1"].str.replace(r'^.*\\\s*', '')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for commenting, I tried your code but it did not work as expected because if i have anothe word after Hello the code will keep only the word after the last space            
  "absc \ efgcvc \ Hello Brother"                                                                                                                       your code will keep only "Brother". I do not understand why?! keep in my mind there is a space between each word and delimiter "\"

Comment: I somehow doubt that you are using my code.

Comment: no I sure am using ur line code. how to prove it? am I able to attach here?

Comment: @OmarAhmed Please check [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CfL6Zt/1) to see that the replacement is working.

Comment: actually i changed data type for my column and it worked. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1':['absc \ efgcvc \ Hello','hij \ klsm \ Hey','qssdrs \ uv \ yellow']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['column1'])
for i in range (0,3,1):
    a = df.iloc[i,0];
    a = (a.split(' \ '))
    df2 = df2.append({'column1': a[2]}, ignore_index=True)

print(df2)
```